# java app deadlock but unlocked after use jstack to dump thread

Tags: java, hibernate, deadlock, c3p0, jstack

My java app is sometime freezing so I dump thread with jstack -F
but the report show no deadlock and app became responsive again ?
anyone know what happened ?

My app using hibernate 4.1.8, jetty 9M2, mysql connector 5.1.22, c3p0 0.9.2.pre6.
the thread dump seem blocked everywhere:
the log file is a bit long so I uploaded it here http://pastebin.com/vDCd6Kjb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this in doc

```
The process is suspended when this connector attaches and resumed when this connector detaches.
```

back to find where the deadlock is